# Where do I find the primary evidence for regulatory relationships included in RegulonDB?

Tags: chip-seq

When I look up high-throughout (ChIP) evidence for binding of the ferric uptake regulator Fur to sites in the genome of *E. coli*, [RegulonDB lists](http://regulondb.ccg.unam.mx/highthroughputdatasets?term=HTRI00000827) a whopping 4214 targets. (To repeat this search, go to the [downloads page](https://regulondb.ccg.unam.mx/central_panel_menu/downloads_menu.jsp), click on "High-throughput datasets",  enter Fur in the *right-most* search box, and click on the fourth link, for `HTRI00000827`.) Some of these have the same gene (alternate promoters?), but I think over 2,000 unique target genes are given. When I click through to the supporting citation, [Seo et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms5910) say "Collectively, a total of 98 Fur-binding sites were newly identified in this study[.]" Clearly I'm missing something here. Why does RegulonDB list so many more target genes than the original paper? What's the evidence, if not ChIP? Thanks!

Edit: I've tried to reach out to RegulonDB using the contact form on their website, but I am unable to pass their captcha test! `I am uncertain what the problem could be. My protocols are completely up to date.` I will update the question if I manage to contact them.

Edit: the paper describing incorporation of ChIP data into RegulonDB is [here](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12915-018-0555-y). It is obviously well-informed, including senior authors from labs behind multiple ChIP datasets. Tables 4 and 5 describe the quantity of new interactions added and are closer to the original reference than to what I am seeing from the website.

Comment: I've looked into this a little and I can't find an answer. If I had to guess, the 4214 targets represent sequences with *any* number of ChIP hits, and the final 98 Fur-binding sites are those with ChIP peaks above the described threshold with paired RNA-seq showing the effect of Fur on expression at those loci. It's a bit frustrating that the "Effect" column of the dataset is "not determined" for all positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached out to the maintainers, and these results are derived from *re-analysis of the raw reads obtained from GEO.* This is described in the [regulonDB 10.5 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6324031/) sections "HT dataset processing" and "Reconstructing regulatory interactions". The processing pipeline, described in fig S1, is fairly typical -- finding motif matches in MACS2 peaks. The cutoff used was simply lower than the source paper, yielding more hits.

Edit: This pipeline description also explains why the tables you download contain duplicates (same regulator, same target). Duplicates can arise from different binding sites upstream of the same gene.

[image: A bioinformatics pipeline for processing RNA-seq and ChIP data from GEO includes peak calling (MACS2), binding-site search (RSAT), and RNA differential expression (FDR-corrected t-test).]